# Put HTML Divs Into PouchDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, pouchdb

I want to put an HTML div (and all its contents) into a JSON object and save it to a PouchDB database.

My div looks like this:

```
<div class="easel">
    <div class="square" style="background-color: white;"></div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: white;"></div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: rgb(85, 222, 25);"></div><div class="square" style="background-color: white;"></div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: white;"></div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: white;"></div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: white;"></div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: rgb(164, 101, 52);"></div><div class="square" style="background-color: white;"></div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: white;"></div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: white;"></div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: rgb(214, 15, 77);"></div><div class="square" style="background-color: white;"></div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: white;"></div>
    <div class="square" style="background-color: white;"></div>
</div>
```

I wrote a function like this:

```
window.saveBoard = function() {
    var db = new PouchDB('tiles');
    var remoteCouch = false;
    var current_layout = $('.easel');
    var new_board = {
        _id: new Date().toISOString(),
        board: current_layout
    }
    db.put(new_board, function callback(err, result) {
        if(!err) {
            console.log("Successfully saved new board.");
        }
    })
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be doing what I want and I'm getting this error in the Console: `Uncaught DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': An object could not be cloned.`

What do I need to do to store this div info in order to get it back later to feed into a page?

Comment: You may want to grab the HTML using `$('.easel').html()` rather than the element as an object. May not be related to your issue though.

Comment: It looks like it's saving now, so thank you for that. The results I'm pulling from the database look like this:

Promise {cancel: function, [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: Object}cancel: function (){return this}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"[[PromiseValue]]: Objectoffset: 0rows: Array[3]total_rows: 3__proto__: Object

Do you know how I can get the arrays of divs with that [[PromiseValue]] thing?

Comment: Are you using jQuerys Ajax or Angulars $http to perform the GET request? Those methods you listed are just promises on the call, doesn't look like the actual data from the server.

Comment: No, I'm not. From what I can see in the PouchDB docs (http://pouchdb.com/api.html), db.allDocs is all I need to do.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I saw your newer question and didn't realize that's how you're getting the results. I don't have experience with PouchDB so I'll let the other people answer, Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can't store HTML elements directly in PouchDB; you can only store straight-up JSON. So you will need to convert your div to some data structure format before storing.